# Used Canvas in jetpack compose to create Spinwheel

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

created a Spin wheel with Canvas in Jetpack compose. This wheel rotates and when it stops, it displays a Dialog with a Text that lands under the Pointer. The problem is the Text displayed on the Dialog is different from the Text or string under the Pointer.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MH8Zj.jpg)

fun determineSelectedCompanyName(rotationAngle: Float, projects: List): String {
val totalTextAmount = projects.size
val sweepAnglePercentage = 360f / totalTextAmount

```
// Calculate the normalized rotation angle to fit within 360 degrees
val normalizedRotation = (rotationAngle % 360 + 360) % 360

// Calculate the angle to the arrow's tip (adjust this angle as needed)
val arrowTipAngle = 0f // Assuming the arrow is centered at 180 degrees

// Calculate the index of the selected item based on the angle to the arrow's tip
val selectedItemIndex =
    ((normalizedRotation - arrowTipAngle + 360) % 360) / sweepAnglePercentage

// Return the corresponding text or project string
return projects[selectedItemIndex.toInt()]
```

}

```
val projects = viewModel.scannedProjects.collectAsState(emptyList())

Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(), contentAlignment = Alignment.Center) {
    val firstTimeClicked = remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    val showDialog = remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    val coroutineScope = rememberCoroutineScope()
    val rotating = rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf(false) }
    val companyName = remember { mutableStateOf("") } // Store the selected company name
    val randomAngle = remember { mutableFloatStateOf(0f) }

    if (!rotating.value) {
        if (!firstTimeClicked.value) {
            randomAngle.floatValue = (360..920).random().toFloat()
            firstTimeClicked.value = true
        } else if (showDialog.value) {
            // Show the dialog after the first rotation is finished
            WheelDialog(
                onDismiss = { showDialog.value = false },
                onTurnAgain = {
                    randomAngle.floatValue = (360..920).random().toFloat()
                    rotating.value = true
                },
                text = companyName.value,
            )
        }
    }

    WheelAnimation(
        randomAngle = randomAngle,
        rotating = rotating,
        projects = projects.value,
        onRotationFinished = { selectedProject ->
            companyName.value = selectedProject
            rotating.value = false
            // Delay and show the dialog
            coroutineScope.launch {
                delay(3000)
                showDialog.value = true
            }
        },
        firstTimeClicked = firstTimeClicked,
    )

    RefreshButton(rotating = rotating, coroutineScope = coroutineScope)

    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .align(Alignment.TopCenter),
    ) {
        WheelPointer()
    }
}
```

}

I have used the Debug to check the what data goes to companyName and it does not correspond with the Text und the wheel Pointer.